# correct use of the cflock tag ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I know the correct way of using `<cflock>` is quite a large topic of conversation on the www for cf developers.

As I'm trying to understand it a little bit better, I've got a simple UDF I've created which takes in a session array and I'm wondering whether this is a correct way of doing it considering it's a simple UDF.

```
<cffunction name="currentCartQuantity" access="public" returntype="string">
<cfargument name="partnumber" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="data" type="array" required="yes">

<cfset var return_data = "0" >
<cflock type="readonly" scope="session" timeout="1">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(arguments.data)#" index="idx">
        <cfif arguments.data[idx].partnumber IS arguments.partnumber >
            <cfset return_data = arguments.data[idx].quantity >    
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cflock>
<cfreturn return_data >
</cffunction>
```

It's a simple function which takes in an argument of an array type, which is a session variable of a shopping cart. It also takes in a numeric `partnumber`. Then searches the array of structs to find the matching value.

As this is a session array, I figured I would apply a `cflock` to it, so that it knows to lock the reading of the array down, in case there are any differences on the CF Versions, I have coded this using ColdFusion 8, and I'm hoping any seasoned CF developers would be able to confirm that this is the correct way of locking down the reading of session variables.

This function could be processed up to 200 times when a page is loading, is this the best way to handle this type of data with a `cflock` ?

Comment: I don't see the array changing value in any way so why lock the session scope?  Not related to your question, but your function return something that is based on only the final array element, not each array element.

Comment: The idea being that *other requests* could be changing the array, Dan, and the lock was protecting *this code* from that. It's a moot point though, given the situation (as per my answer). As for your other observation... yeah, good point. I think they perhaps might want to `break` from the loop once they've found their value.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are copied by value in ColdFusion, so that's not the array in session scope, it's a copy of it. No need to lock it.

But there *is* a need to make sure all your function-local variables are `VAR`ed: `idx` is not.

Comment: @user125264 - While it does not apply in this case, one caveat: it is a shallow copy. If the array contents are complex objects (structure, ...) those complex objects are *not* passed by value and would need to be locked.

Comment: Good point. In which case I'd mull over where the locking should take place...I'd probably err towards keeping the code decoupled / encapsulated, and lock the calling code, not within the UDF.